# No files found - print folders and file list using a service google account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I enabled the google drive api, created a service account, added the service account email to the folder and successfully generated the .json credentials
But when I try to print the contents of the temp2 folder I get "no files found"
I'm attempting to do it this way

```
import logging
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('bayfiles-779393795f34.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.presentation' and trashed = false and parents in '16x7o7CNCscM-lFqnKaXwUf1Bv-OTQK0W'"

results = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
items = results.get("files", [])

if not items:
    logger.debug("No files found")
else:
    
    # Print file names
    for item in items:
        logger.debug(f'The service account has access to the file "{item["name"]}" with ID "{item["id"]}"')
```

The strange thing is that the number of requests appears to me in the API page of my project

[image]

but through the code it is returned to me as if there were no files inside the temp2 folder, but it's wrong.

Comment: You have an issue in your query. Add parenthesis. Start by deleting some parts (like trash condition)... Finally, where are you running your code?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm running the code from the Windows Powershell terminal because I want to modify it for other purposes, such as creating text files with the list of urls of my google folders. Should I run it from google cloud?

Comment: Powershell is a possible platform, no problem at all. the problem come from the service account key file usage. it will work with it, but it's a bad practice to generate and use it. Prefer your personal account with `gcloud auth application-default login` command, even on powershell!!

Comment: About the filter, put into (parenthesis) all the OR conditions. I thinks it's your main issue.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I try to rewrite query in this way `query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and ('16x7o7CNCscM-lFqnKaXwUf1Bv-OTQK0W')"` but I get this error: `PS C:\temp\bayfiles> python verifica_accesso_account_servizio.py
INFO:googleapiclient.discovery_cache:file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
DEBUG:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27+and+trashed+%3D+false+and+%28%2716x7o7CNCscM-lFqnKaXwUf1Bv-OTQK0W%27%29&alt=json
`

Comment: `DEBUG:google_auth_httplib2:Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\bayfiles\verifica_accesso_account_servizio.py", line 21, in <module>
    results = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in `

Comment: `execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27+and+trashed+%3D+false+and+%28%2716x7o7CNCscM-lFqnKaXwUf1Bv-OTQK0W%27%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Value', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'q', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested locally, with my user account and your filter and your code works well. But as I said, strangely.

In fact, only the presentation not trashed in the mentioned folder are returned + all the other file mentioned in the OR clauses. Again, add parenthesis like that to narrow only to the current mentioned folder

```
query = "(mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.presentation') and trashed = false and parents in '16x7o7CNCscM-lFqnKaXwUf1Bv-OTQK0W'"
```

Are you sure about the Folder ID?

---

Let me show you how to avoid a service account key file (which is a bad practice).

1. You have to scope correctly your user credential. Use that CLI command for that

```
gcloud auth application-default login \
  --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

*Keep in mind that is now your user account that will be used, and YOUR email must be granted on the Google Drive folder*

If you want to use the service account identity instead of your own user email, you can use impersonation

```
gcloud auth application-default login \
  --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" \
  --impersonate-service-account="<service account email>"
```

*You must have the role "project owner" or "service account token creator" to be able to impersonate a service account. But like that, you don't need a secret and sensitive file (JSON)*

2. Update your code. You will see 2 changes

```
import logging
#from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials -- No longer need it
import google.auth #Required for getting the default authentication
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('bayfiles-779393795f34.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

# Prefer the default credential instead. Like that it works locally and in the cloud  the same way
# Scopes are optional locally, but required in the cloud runtime environment
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"])

# With your user credential you also have to notify explicitly the quota project. It's optional for cloud runtime environment
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials,client_options={"quota_project_id":project_id})


query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.presentation' and trashed = false and parents in '16x7o7CNCscM-lFqnKaXwUf1Bv-OTQK0W'"

results = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
items = results.get("files", [])

if not items:
    logger.debug("No files found")
else:
    
    # Print file names
    for item in items:
        logger.debug(f'The service account has access to the file "{item["name"]}" with ID "{item["id"]}"')
```

Comment: ok, thank you but I see a little problem: it show me only ID of folders but not ID of files, look here the output of from Google CLI terminal - https://pastebin.com/raw/iYUPESbF

Comment: The things I did are basically two: **1**. I used the Google Cloud CLI SDK from the terminal to be able to log in to my project, which was not done before, so the authorization token was not generated when I used powershell and therefore first of all I got a response ""*You are now authenticated with the gcloud CLI!The authentication flow has completed successfully. You may close this window, or check out the resources below.*" **2** Else I set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path to the login credentials JSON file for authenticating with the Google Cloud service

Comment: To do this i then used this command in terminal `"set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\credentials.json"` - **3**. Then I run from terminal yout python script using python script.py - **4**. - I also add my service account as folder sharing user (set as 'Editor'), from Google drive API settings user is set to Owner